# Finding an old incoming friend request on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I got a friend request from someone a month ago, approved it, and in the meantime, I forgot his name. I would like review all friend requests I got in the last month, to help jog my memory.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: That is a very different question, which asks how to see the *message* that was associated with the friend request for a particular friend.

Comment: @mark4o - hmm, never caught on to that subtleties. Ok then.

Comment: If I understand correctly, Facebook does not offer to attach a note to a friend request anymore. So the "duplicate" question is about something that does not exist anymore, and the present question is valid and different. And the answer on each question is right for its question, and different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Timeline, click on your name at the top to go to your Timeline, then click **Activity Log**, and then switch from showing all activity (**All** in the upper right corner) to **Friends**.  This will show your recent friends along with the date and time that you became friends.

Comment: Dunno if it works or not, but I accepted. You should really post it at the duplicate question that I linked to above.